# Disable type to search at Start Menu on Win10 LTSB

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-10

I'm trying to find out a way of completely disabling the type to search option on Win10's start menu.

I have tried several combinations of GPs to do so but all of them have been unsuccessful.

My main thing to achieve is to disallow this all together in order to prevent users from opening applications the IE etc.

Comment: That won't work. Searching the Start menu isn't a primary way of launching applications in Windows. Users can utilize the Run window, double-click an executable etc...

Comment: All these actions have been disallowed already. I have for example disabled all the cmd + x keys and the start menu does not show any applications other than the ones I want it to.

Search feature though allow this indirectly. For example you can search for 'cmd' and it'll let you fire up a command prompt.

Answer (score 0):

How to remove search bar from Windows 10 Taskbar:
1. Right click on a blank area of the Taskbar.
2. Select the Cortana submenu and select Hidden.
3. If you want to keep the option of quick search on the Taskbar you can select the option Show Cortana Icon.

I got this from: http://www.alphr.com/operating-systems/1000347/how-to-remove-the-search-bar-from-windows-10-taskbar

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I have done this already. What I want to do is to disable the start menu's search feature. That is the one that automatically start searching for files once a user starts typing with the start menu open.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that unless you disable Windows search feature completely via this PowerShell:

**Dism /online /Disable-Feature /FeatureName:SearchEngine-Client-Package**

Alternatively, disable the **Windows Search service**.

Comment: I have tried disabling the service manually but the start menu search is seemingly still available. Haven't tried the ps cmd above but I'm gonna give it a shot.

Comment: OK, even though this seems to have disable it, after restarting the type on search with the start menu opened is still available. It seems that this does not work as intended.